# Get Json string from http response.body()

Tags: java, json, httpresponse

I would like to know if there's any way to extract a Json string from a `http response.body()`. Inside my `response.body()` I have: `{"er":"manualBlock"}` and I would like to deal with this string without having to use the split method.

Edit
I have this so far:

```
String[] parts = response.body().string().split("-"); 
        result = parts[0]; 

if (result != null && result.equals("{\"er\":\"manualBlock\"}")) {
          throw new BlockeduserException("User blocked", null);
        }
```

Comment: What HTTP client do you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I am using Retrofit.

Comment: Also, could you please paste the code you currently have?

Comment: implement toString method in your Response class and do like this **response.body.toString()**

Comment: I just added the code that I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by creating a class like this:

```
public class BlockResponse {

    public String er;
}
```

And then I used the google-Gson to handle everything by doing this:

```
String serverResponse = response.body().string();
Gson gson = new Gson();
result = gson.fromJson(serverResponse, BlockResponse.class);
```

And for the comparison I used:

```
if (result != null && result.er.equals("manualBlock")) {
    throw new BlockeduserException("User blocked", null);
}
```